# how to get the selected radio button label's ID in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="dynamic" id="label1id">    </label>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="dynamic"></input>
<label for="dynamic1" id="label2id"></label>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="dynamic1"></input><br>
<label for="dynamic2" id="label3id"></label>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="dynamic2"></input>
<label for="dynamic3" id="label4id"></label>
<input type="radio" name="rafio2" id="dynamic3"></input>
```

Actually what I was trying to ask is that how to check that the radio button is selected and if it is selected the label should be of different colour And if it not selected in that case it should be of different colour...
And in my functionality there are more then one set of radio button and they are selected dynamically I created a java script for it the code which I used is 
    
    Function radioclick (){
    If (document.getElementById ('dynamic').checked){
    Document.getElementById ('label1id').color="red";
    Document.getElementById ('label2id').color="black";
    }
    Else {
       Document.getElementById('label2id').color="red";
    Document.getElementById.('label1id').color="black";
    }
    }
    
Using the hard coded id's it won't work when the I'd are getting generated dynamically.
 Now I think I have cleared the question
But thanks for the reply again I'll try that code and will post the answer once ill be able to implement it.
kindly help stuck on this since a long time....

Comment: The first label and input in your HTML have the same `id` attribute value, which isn't valid in HTML (ID has to be unique).

Comment: If the radio button is selected, it should appear with different color text, or it's associated label should appear with different color text?

Answer (score 0):

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpjx4qnc/) for the complete solution.

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("click", function () {
        $("label").css({color:'black'});
        $(this).prev().css({color:'red'});
    })
});
```

Comment: I have made the changes is the question.. Thanks for the reply will try to use the suggestion given by you